# build_depend vs build_export_depend vs exec_depend in ROS with Python?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, add-dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the context of using ROS with Python, how would the `build_depend`, `build_export_depend` and `exec_depend` differ?

Since Python is an interpreted language, can I understand it as they should all be the same? How would there be a build process (perhaps excluding the case when we use Cython or other C++ based Python extensions).

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324090/build_depend-vs-build_export_depend-vs-exec_depend-in-ros-with-python?/) by [Sparkle Eyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/38320/sparkle-eyes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 99 on 2019-05-27

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are correct, that there is no build process per se with python-only packages. Note though, that you still need the `CMakeLists.txt` for `catkin` to function properly.

In the end, the `build_depend` and `build_export_depend` tags are practically irrelevant for python-only packages. You only need to specify your python-based dependencies via `exec_depend`.

[The catkin docs](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/python_module_dependencies.html) state, however, to import any message packages using the `depend` tag, even though `exec_depend` would be enough. Though I'm not sure why that's the case...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2019-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sparkle Eyes](https://answers.ros.org/users/38320/sparkle-eyes/) on 2019-05-28**:
Thanks for the answer! The link to the doc is very useful.